# Recording screen with pulseaudio causes desyncs

Tags: x11, pulseaudio, alsa, video, ffmpeg

Following the [ffmpeg's Capturing Desktop guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) for linux, when audio source is pulse format it causes frame freezes and desyncs, fps slows down, and video is delayed compared to audio.

I have tried several arguments' combinations that  I have found in my research trying to fix this issue, following is the current command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg \
  -video_size 1920x1080 \
  -framerate 60 \
  -f x11grab \
  -probesize 42M \
  -thread_queue_size 64 \
  -i :0.0 \
  -f pulse \
  -thread_queue_size 64 \
  -i default \
  -c:v libx264rgb \
  -crf 0 \
  -preset ultrafast \
  -c:a aac \
  -ac 2 \
  -b:a 160k \
  -ar 44100 \
  -strict experimental \
  -threads 8 \
  -vsync vfr \
  -max_muxing_queue_size 64 \
  -f mp4 \
  -y o.mp4
```

But the funny fact is that if I replace the audio source for `-f alsa -i pulse` it works and the warning message "*100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.*" is gone.

I'm using the version **4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1**, since pulse is more versatile, allowing volume control by application and custom modules, I'd like ffmpeg would work fine with pulse.

Evidences: https://youtu.be/rhjfQNd5lP4

Here is my default source (`pactl list sources`):

```
Source #1
        State: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_27_00.3.analog-stereo
        Description: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Estéreo analógico
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 9
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 19661 /  30% / -31.37 dB,   front-right: 19661 /  30% / -31.37 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB
        Monitor of Sink: n/a
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC892 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC892 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfe800000 irq 69"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:27:00.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:27:00.3/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "1457"
                device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
                device.access_mode = "mmap"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Estéreo analógico"
                device.description = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Estéreo analógico"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Ports:
                analog-input-front-mic: Microfone frontal (priority: 8500, available)
                analog-input-rear-mic: Microfone traseiro (priority: 8200, not available)
                analog-input-linein: Entrada de linha (priority: 8100, not available)
        Active Port: analog-input-front-mic
        Formats:
                pcm
```

As I don't know if this problem is due to my audio card or a missing ffmpeg's setting, could you please try the command I've tried and feed me back if it worked for you or not? And if you have any idea I could try in order to make it work please help me out.

Comment: turn your fps down

Comment: @johndoe I have tried it, same problem, it is not CPU, since keeping the same parameters and replacing just pulse to alsa it works straight with 60 fps, I must have missing something or it is a bug...

Comment: Now I have tried `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` and it fixed fps but caused audio skips and the error message "*Queue input is backward in time*" and "*Non-monotonous DTS in output stream*" to show.